# How to handle a string with quotes in it?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a java script function which i am calling through:

```
 <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='javascript:onEditRevPrepare("   <%#Convert.ToString(Eval("ReviewTitle"))%>">
```

Problem is that when `Eval("ReviewTitle")` is having single quote or double quote in it, function is not get called.

I think the problem is due to(not sure due to this or not):

```
Convert.Tostring(....)
```

but also i need to convert it into string before i pass it to javascript function.

What can i do?

Javascript function:

```
function onEditRevPrepare(revTitle)
{

...
...
}
```

Comment: `Eval` isn't a C# function so what are you trying to do there? To escape a string? `String.Replace` would be enough for that (to replace character you're using as string delimiter only, for example `\'` instead of `'` if `'` is your string delimiter).

Comment: @Adriano but i wanted to pass string as it is to javascript function (with "" or ') ... eval is in asp.net

Comment: So just `Convert.ToString(Eval("ReviewTitle")).Replace("\"", "\\\"")` should do proper escaping

Comment: @Adriano wait sir, i will try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `&quot;`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/2Eyag/)**

```
onclick='javascript:onEditRevPrepare(&quot;<%#Convert.ToString(Eval("ReviewTitle"))%>&quot;'
```

Comment: Does it give you any error can you show me the generated script?

Comment: phh,,sir i am editing it accordingly, plz wait for me

Comment: If you can share the generated html for anchor tag you have then I might be able to help you.

Comment: You have to escape single quote with back slash, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/2Eyag/2/

Comment: sir in my case, how can i find it dynamically that ' or ""  is present over there ?

Answer (score 1):

You facing problem with some specific values or function is not calling at all ? Please clarify that.

I guess problem is not with **"** as far as if method is not calling at all. Try this and let me know if still having problem.

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='javascript:onEditRevPrepare(" + <%#Convert.ToString(Eval("ReviewTitle"))%> + ">
```

**UPDATED**

I think problem is that you are not closing your function with `)` that you are calling from `onclick` and also replace `'` (if any) with `&#39;`. It should be as below

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='javascript:onEditRevPrepare("<%#Convert.ToString(Eval("ReviewTitle"))%>).Replace("'", "&#39;")">
```

Thanks

Comment: yep, function is not getting called at all when " or ' is involved in the string

Comment: @SagarS.Dhanorkar: see my updated answer and let me know if it works for you or not?